# Can Jenkins be used for Docker Swarm deployment?

Tags: jenkins, docker-swarm

How to automate Jenkins for Docker Swarm deployment.

I am wondering if there are any plugins available in Jenkins which will help in Docker Swarm deployment or any other alternative way through which we can achieve the automation of Swarm deployment using Jenkins existing plugins?

Comment: I use ssh because I prefer having only one set of commands that I need to know about

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try with SSH. That only seems to be the plausible way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this problem by using a plugin called Publish over SSH

Need to install a Jenkins plugins “Publish over SSH”, this plugin will allows us to

- Sends files over SSH(SFTP)
- Execute commands on a remote server

First step will be to add remote hosts and second will be to add an execution/build step where the commands will be executed

Follow [this link for step by step instruction](http://littlebigextra.com/automate-service-deployment-docker-swarm-using-jenkins/)